# Create a month by month archive of pages (not posts)

Tags: archives

Is it possible to create a month by month archive of pages? I know it can be done with posts but I want to do it with pages.

I want it to take the date the page was published so if the page was published in August then it would create a link called "August" which in turn when clicked will show all the pages within August.

Is that possible?

Or is there a better way I can categorise my pages to show them month by month?

UPDATE:
I use this plugin - [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields). Is there any way I could do it with pages? Is there any fields I could add to a page that could help me hack together an archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably hack something together, but you should probably understand that, in WordPress, a basic assumption (and operating principle) is that *static Pages are not chronological*.

IMHO, a better approach would be to store the content as *Blog Posts*, and then to use Categories (or perhaps, a *custom taxonomy*) to identify that content, and to display it chronologically.

If you have a taxonomy (core or custom) that identifies this content, you can even filter your primary Loop query, so that this content does not output with your "normal" Blog Posts.

Comment: Agreed - this is the best approach.

Comment: @Chip I use this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. Is there any way I could do it with pages? Is there any fields I could add to a page that could help me hack together an archive?

Answer (score 0):

Pages are meant for holding timeless content. Are you sure you are in the right direction here? We can create something like domain.com/pages/2011/07 to access all pages published on July 2011 and so on.

About the links, you can generate them wherever you want. I would need your theme, so that I can create a page template that will show the Page listing & a plugin to handle this functionality.

Comment: I use this plugin - wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields. Is there any way I could do it with pages? Is there any fields I could add to a page that could help me hack together an archive?