# History of page, interval of years

Tags: plugins, wp-query, pages, templates, search

I'm having a customer who wants a WordPress page, and I don't have the best overview of the plugins and possibilities for this exact requirement my customer wants.

He arranges an seminar once a year, so for each year the site text and pictures look very different, but the main theme of the page stays the same. When the seminar is over for e.g. 2015, he wants to start fresh with the year 2016. The tricky thing, and my question is: He wants to make it possible to browse the 2013, 2014, 2015 ... (etc) versions of the page. So people can look backwards in the history of seminars. *Now keep in mind this is a page, and not a blog - so you can't just sort blog entries by the year.*

Now obviously the easiest but also the dirtiest trick to do this, is just to copy the database and page into a folder and link it. Though I was wondering if there is a more clean way of doing this - maybe a plugin of some sort or just some functions I did not think about.

It's a big plus, but not the definite requirement that it's easy enough for my customer to perform this yearly sweep on his own. With little knowledge of computers and websites. If not, still tell me your recommendation - then I will just help him that one time a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible. I would say even though you mention that it is a page and not a blog, it can still be achieved.

WordPress works off page templates, so you could essentially just create a new template for every year that you require. You can then assign this template to a new page and it will appear as you want it too.

So your template hierarchy would look like the following:

- page-2016.php
- page-2015.php
- page-2014.php

And so on and so on. You would also then need to set the HomePage for the site (I'm assuming this is how you have it set up at the moment?) as the relevant year. You can then have a navigation menu, that would list previous years. With a bit of styling you could turn it into a drop down version under a main page of 'Seminar Archives' and then have each page as a sub-page of 'Seminar Archives';

Doing it this way also eliminates the need to duplicate the DB multiple times, as each page would run off the same DB and access the required media.

Each template would need to hold the relevant styling information to make it look the same, and then you can update it as and when the need arises.

This Stack Exchange link also sheds further light on a similar situation.
[Create a month by month archive of pages (not posts)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24821/create-a-month-by-month-archive-of-pages-not-posts) (But this talks about a month-by-month rather than just a single page for a year?) (You also don't mention whether on the page you list posts for that year related to the seminar?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but [pages can be retrieved](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) by publish date as well, like this:

```
$year = 2015;
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'page'
  'date_query' => array(
     array( 'year'  => $year )),
  ));
```

You can easily make a loop that generates `$year` from a certain starting year until the current year to generate links to all pages from a given year.